# Can a saga put an action which triggers itself?

Tags: redux, redux-saga

I have an saga which takes and action however it also puts this action I thought it would result in an infinite loop but it does bot What am i missing

Answer (score 0):

It is how it works, you probably have a mistake in your code that prevents the loop from happening. try running this code:

```js
function* recursiveSaga({ count }) {
  console.log({ count });
  if (count > 0) {
    yield put({ type: "FOO", count: count - 1 });
  }
}

function* rootSaga() {
  yield takeEvery("FOO", recursiveSaga);
  yield put({ type: "FOO", count: 10 });
}
```

As you can see it runs 10 times until the count reaches zero.